# Javascript 'Firefly' background causing website delay lag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For the background of my website i am using a Firefly effect where particles move over the background image randomly, i however find that the script is causing the website to have a delay lag which is very noticeable.

Here is a JSfiddle of the firefly effect which i am using:

jsfiddle.net/uyk7a711/1/

I have two questions, firstly being is there any way i can optimise this code or change anything to make it have less lag on the viewers computer ?

Secondly a rather silly question, can i change the colour of the particles ?

Any help would really be appreciated.

Thankyou all

Comment: Why has this been down voted ?

Comment: most likely reason for the down vote is that we have to go elsewhere for your code. It should be included in the question itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter the colour of the particles here:

```
con.createRadialGradient(this.x,this.y,0,this.x,this.y,(cr <= 0 ? 1 : cr));
        g.addColorStop(0.0, 'rgba(255,255,255,'+newo+')');
        g.addColorStop(this.stop, 'rgba(122,117,175,'+(newo*.4)+')');
        g.addColorStop(1.0, 'rgba(122,117,175,0)');
        con.fillStyle = g;
        con.fill();
    }
```

Just change the rgba values to the colours you want to.